# Next.js not re-rendering UI on state change

Tags: css, next.js, toggle, use-state, react-state-management

On my Next js project I am looping through an array of amenities that displays a div that when clicked toggles an active prop. The addAmenity function handles the logic that loops through the amenities array and toggles the specific array item's active property. If the active prop of the div is true the .amenities-active class is supposed to be applied to it and the background of the div should turn green but it does not. Is there any idea as to what I am doing wrong. The console.log(tempList) confirms a change to true when clicked on a false amenity but the UI does not change to have a green background color.

```
//Next js

const amenitiesDefaultArr = [
    {
        data: "bathroom",
        text: "Private Bathroom",
        icon: <WcIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    },
    {
        data: "dining",
        text: "Dining Hall",
        icon: <FastfoodIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    },
    {
        data: "wifi",
        text: "Wifi",
        icon: <WifiIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    }
]

const addAmenity = (e) => { 
        let dataItem = e.currentTarget.dataset.amenity
        let tempList = amenitiesList

        tempList.map(el => {
            if (el.data === dataItem) el.active = !el.active
            return el
        })

        console.log(tempList)
        setAmenitiesList(tempList)
    }

const AddDorm = () => {
    const [amenitiesList, setAmenitiesList] = useState(amenitiesDefaultArr)

    return (
        <>
         {
            amenitiesList.map(el => {
                const {data, text, icon } = el
                let { active } = el

            return (
                <div 
                    className={`amenity ${active && `amenity-active`}`} 
                    key={data} 
                    data-amenity={data}
                    onClick={(e) => addAmenity(e)}
                 >
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    {icon}
                </div>
           )
         </>
        })   
    )
```

```
/* CSS */
.amenity {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #919191,
              -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
  z-index: 4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.amenity-active {
  background-color: var(--green);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are trying to pass data in a `JSX` element as you would do in `html`.

```
data-amenity={data}
```

React does work this way.So, `e.currentTarget.dataset.amenity` is always `undeined`.Instead, React uses `ref`s to access dom elements. You can learn more about `ref`s in the official React documentation. But in your case, you don't even need any `ref` as you can send data directly to any function. Check:

```
<div 
    className={`amenity ${active && `amenity-active`}`} 
    key={data} 
    // data-amenity={data}
    onClick={() => addAmenity(data)}
    >
    <p>{text}</p>
</div>
```

and in `addAmenity` just receive it

```
const addAmenity = (incoming) => {
    let dataItem = incoming
    ...
}
```

Below I provide the version of your code I fixed for you which is working perfect. Please let me know if this was helpful.

```
//Next js
import { useState } from 'react'
const amenitiesDefaultArr = [
    {
        data: "bathroom",
        text: "Private Bathroom",
        icon: <WcIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    },
    {
        data: "dining",
        text: "Dining Hall",
        icon: <FastfoodIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    },
    {
        data: "wifi",
        text: "Wifi",
        icon: <WifiIcon fontSize="large" />,
        active: false,
    }
]



const AddDorm = () => {
    const [amenitiesList, setAmenitiesList] = useState(amenitiesDefaultArr)

    const addAmenity = (incoming) => {
        let dataItem = incoming

       const tempList = amenitiesList.map(el => {
            if (el.data === dataItem) el.active = !el.active
            return el
        })

        console.log(tempList)
        setAmenitiesList(tempList)
    }

    return (
      <>
         {
            amenitiesList.map(el => {
                const {data, text, icon} = el
                let { active } = el

            return (
                <div 
                    className={`amenity ${active && `amenity-active`}`} 
                    key={data} 
                    // data-amenity={data}
                    onClick={() => addAmenity(data)}
                 >
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    {icon}
                </div>
           )})}
      </> 
    )
}

export default AddDorm
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but the issue still remains. The active value changes when I console log the tempList array but the .amentity-active class still isn't applied to it

Comment: The problem was that you were mapping through the list. `Array.prototype.map` returns a new array but you were not saving it. I improved the code. If this is what your expected result, please accept my answer or upvote